# TikZ matrix with dotted node borders but not on the first row

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Is it possible to have the first row with undotted borders, whereas in the rest of the column they are dotted, without drawing the lines with `\draw`?

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
    matrstandard/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    }, 
    nodostandard/.style={
        text height=1.75ex, 
        text depth=.25ex,
    },
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[matrstandard,
            nodes={draw=gray, nodostandard, anchor=base},
            row 1/.style={
                nodes={draw=gray, fill=gray!50!white,font=\bfseries, text centered}},
            row 5/.style={nodes={font=\small, text height=2.5ex}},
            column 1/.style={
                nodes={draw=gray, fill=gray!50!white,font=\bfseries, align=left, text width=1em}},
            column 2/.style={nodes={align=left, dotted, text width=4em}},
            column 3/.style={nodes={align=left, dotted, text width=3em}},
            column 4/.style={nodes={align=right, dotted, text width=3em}},
            column 5/.style={nodes={align=right, dotted, text width=4em}},
            column 6/.style={nodes={align=right, dotted, text width=4em}},
            ] (M) {
            & Name & Sex & Age &Height &Weight\\
            1 & Alfred & M & 14 & 69 & 112.5 \\
            2 & Alice & F & 13 & 56.5 & 84 \\
            3 & Barbara & F & 13 & 65.3 & 98 \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I know that the layout is poor but I'm trying to replicate this (a dataset as displayed by SAS Enterprise Guide):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Sorry, I've found the solution immediately after posting the question (but maybe this could be useful for someone else).</sup>

It's enough to use `solid` as a node option in the first row:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
    matrstandard/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    }, 
    nodostandard/.style={
        text height=1.75ex, 
        text depth=.25ex,
    },
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[matrstandard,
            nodes={draw=gray, nodostandard, anchor=base},
            row 1/.style={
                nodes={draw=gray, solid, fill=gray!50!white,font=\bfseries, text centered}},
            row 5/.style={nodes={font=\small, text height=2.5ex}},
            column 1/.style={
                nodes={draw=gray, fill=gray!50!white,font=\bfseries, align=left, text width=1em}},
            column 2/.style={nodes={align=left, dotted, text width=4em}},
            column 3/.style={nodes={align=left, dotted, text width=3em}},
            column 4/.style={nodes={align=right, dotted, text width=3em}},
            column 5/.style={nodes={align=right, dotted, text width=4em}},
            column 6/.style={nodes={align=right, dotted, text width=4em}},
            ] (M) {
            & Name & Sex & Age &Height &Weight\\
            1 & Alfred & M & 14 & 69 & 112.5 \\
            2 & Alice & F & 13 & 56.5 & 84 \\
            3 & Barbara & F & 13 & 65.3 & 98 \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]